# Struggling to read in JSON file in Angular 2+ project

Tags: html, angular, web-applications, dependency-injection, single-page-application

I have used the Angular CLI to set up this project so the standard folder layout holds. I am trying to practice reading in a JSON file from src/app/assets/items.json and use it to display these items in the html.

items.json:

```
{
   "results": [
      "Item 1",
      "Item 2",
    ]
}
```

app.service.ts in src/app/:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

// Import RxJs required methods
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
    private greetUrl = 'api/Hello';

    // Resolve HTTP using the constructor
    constructor(private _http: Http) { }

    findJSON(): Observable<any> {
        return this._http.get('assets/items.json').map((response: Response) => {
            return response.json();
        });
    }

    sayHello(): Observable<any> {
        return this._http.get(this.greetUrl).map((response: Response) => {
            return response.text();
        });
    }
}
```

and app.component.ts in src/app:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  greetings = '';
  itemsjson : string;

  constructor(private _appService: AppService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._appService.findJSON()
      .subscribe(
      result => {
        this.itemsjson = result;
      }
      );
  }
}
```

and app.component.html in src/app/:

```
<html lang="en">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Yik-Yak Clone</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a href="../" class="navbar-brand">Yik-Yak Clone</a>
        </div>
      </div>      
    </div>

      <!-- Containers
      ================================================== -->
      <div class = "container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="bs-component">
              <div class="jumbotron">
                <h1>{{itemsjson}}</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div> 
      </div>

      <!-- Containers
      ================================================== -->
      <div class = "container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="bs-component">
              <div class="jumbotron">
                <h1>{{itemsjson}}</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div> 
      </div>

          <!-- 
      ================================================== -->
      <div class = "container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="bs-component">
              <div class="jumbotron">
                <h1>{{itemsjson}}</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div> 
      </div> 


  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-head">
        <div class = "col-sm-3"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" id="inputLarge">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "navbar-brand">
          <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="form-group">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">greetings</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "col-sm-1"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  </body>
</html>
```

Every example online and similar question online seems to imply that this is all correct.

Comment: What are you expecting to get from items.json?

Comment: I was hoping to be able call "Item 1" into one Jumbotron and "Item 2" into another Jumbotron

Comment: I was hoping that the first iteration would be printing them both into one jumbotron

Comment: Assuming you get the json back, you should be seeing `<h1>[Object object]</h1>` I think you are wanting to use an `*ngFor` to loop through your result array

Comment: Ok yeah that would be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to be looping through your results property returned by your json.

```
<div class ="container" *ngFor="let item of itemsjson?.results">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="bs-component">
                <div class="jumbotron">
                    <h1>{{item}}</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

We also are using the safe navigation operator (?) because itemsjson is not initially defined `itemsjson?.results`

Comment: This looks much cleaner but leaves me with no jumbotrons

Comment: @Permian what do you mean by no jumbotrons? the `<div class="jumbotron">`

Comment: yeah bootstrap bit https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/jumbotron/

Comment: @Permian each item in `itemsjson.results` gets it own DOM block (the html that I posted). so each item gets its own jumbotron

Comment: I see what its meant to be do but when it ng build and look at the app locally no jumbotrons are showing

Comment: @Permian Are you getting any errors? Do you see those elements in the debug tools? (perhaps {{item}}) is not populating correctly causing the height of those elements to be 0). I'll need more info to debug the problem

Comment: Problems: items.json src/assets (1) Value expected (5,5)

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157939/discussion-between-llai-and-permian).

Comment: Nothing in debug console

Answer (score 1):

There is nowhere you are using **`itemsjson`** in your HTML, probably you need

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>{{itemsjson | json }}</h1> 
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry there was a slight in the question above in the html. This hasnt worked either, why are you piping json?

Answer (score 1):

First, check your `itemsjson` on `console.log` and just pass it in your template. If you want to read your data in loop use - `*ngFor = 'let data of itemsjson;let i = index' and pass {{data}}`.

Comment: Im really not sure what this means

Comment: This is the way through which you can read data and pass it in template.

Comment: have you installed bootstrap in your app?

Comment: yeah i think i have